# How to merge files between computers?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im having trouble to get the `sync option` transfering 100% of my settings between computers, i mean, get everything equal to the host computer.

Would like to ask what folders do i need to copy-paste to get my vscode settings exactly when running on a different computer?

Using Windows10, and the latest version of vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Copying these 3 folders i get everything equal:

```
1-
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs
folder: Microsoft VS Code


2-
C:\Users\UserName
folder: .vscode

3-
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming
folder: Code
```